# Find Unique Hex Sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I'm trying to find unique hex "strings"(?) (unique occurrence of a hex section).

Example input:

```
F6 03 04 AA F3 03 03 AA F7 03 00 AA F4 02 40 F9 F3 03 03 AA F7 03 00 AA F4 02 40 F9
E8 51 00 F0 08 B1 2A 91 E0 03 14 AA E1 03 02 AA 08 B1 2A 91 E0 03 14 AA E1 03 02 AA
E2 03 08 AA 2F 01 00 94 F5 03 00 AA 75 01 00 B4 2F 01 00 94 F5 03 00 AA 75 01 00 B4
E0 03 17 AA E1 03 15 AA E2 03 16 AA 66 01 00 94 E1 03 15 AA E2 03 16 AA 66 01 00 94
F6 03 00 AA F6 00 00 34 E0 03 14 AA E1 03 15 AA F6 00 00 34 E0 03 14 AA E1 03 15 AA
F9 04 00 94 05 00 00 14 F6 03 1A 32 03 00 00 14 05 00 00 14 F6 03 1A 32 03 00 00 14
16 00 80 52 75 02 00 F9 E0 03 16 AA FD 7B 43 A9 75 02 00 F9 E0 03 16 AA FD 7B 43 A9
F4 4F 42 A9 F6 57 41 A9 F8 5F C4 A8 C0 03 5F D6 F6 57 41 A9 F8 5F C4 A8 C0 03 5F D6
```

Output:

```
AA F6 00 00 34 E0 03 14 AA E1 03 15 AA F6 00 00 34 E0 03 14
```

*not the realistic output, since I just picked a random unique I could find, but I essentially want it to find a unique hex section with the length 20, that doesn't show up anywhere else in the code.

The sequence is unique because it does not occur anywhere else in the file. And I found 20 to be a reasonable size, to make it easier to find unique sequences. Since in a normal file, short sequences such as, for example, `AA F6` or even `AA E2 03 16 AA 66` will appear multiple times.

Any suggestions on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, please add a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question so the community may help you.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a homework problem. Regardless, it is interesting. This code should work:

```
''' Someone's homework assignment on Stackoverflow '''

import argparse

# When a search for a match comes up empty.
NOT_FOUND = -1

# Print debugging information, increasing values are more verbose.
print_debug = 0

def data_string_to_bytes(data_string):
    '''
    Convert packed string of nybble data to bytes.
    There is expected to be no whitespace intermingled within.
    The number of nybbles must be even.
    '''
    if len(data_string) % 2 != 0:
        raise ValueError('Attempting to parse byte string with odd legnth {}'
                         .format(len(data_string)))
    byte_list = []
    for index in range(0, len(data_string), 2):
        byte_value = int(data_string[index], 16)
        byte_value <<= 8
        byte_value |= int(data_string[index + 1], 16)
        byte_list.append(byte_value)

    return byte_list


def read_hex_file(file_name):
    ''' Read a file of hex values separated by whitespace '''
    read_data = []
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        while True:
            data_line = file.readline()
            if not data_line:
                break

            # Split the line read into whitespace delimited bytes.
            data_string_list = data_line.split()

            # Test the first expected byte string to see if it is the expected
            # size of a whitespace delimited set of bytes.
            if len(data_string_list[0]) > 2:
                # They were not whitespace delimited after all.
                read_data.extend(data_string_to_bytes(data_string_list[0]))
            else:
                data = [int(x, 16) for x in data_string_list]
                read_data.extend(data)

    return read_data


def data_to_string(data):
    ''' Convert an integer list to a string of hex bytes separated by spaces '''
    data_str = ''
    for data_value in data:
        data_str += '%0.2x ' % data_value
    return data_str


def find_window(data, window):
    ''' Winthin a list of data, search for a match of list window '''
    pos_end = (len(data) - len(window)) + 1

    if print_debug > 1:
        print("find_window: data: {}  w: {}".format(data_to_string(data),
                                                    data_to_string(window)))
    for pos in range(pos_end):
        check = data[pos:pos + len(window)]
        if check == window:
            if print_debug > 0:
                print("Found check @   {:4} : {}".format(pos,
                                                         data_to_string(check)))
            return pos

    return NOT_FOUND


def find_unique(data, window_len):
    '''
    Find a unique list of data defined by a window of a given length.
    :data: A list of data in which to search.
    :window_len: The length of the window to search within the data.
    '''
    # Stop searching when there are less than window_len data values remaining.
    pos_end = (len(data) - window_len) + 1
    for pos in range(0, pos_end):
        window = data[pos:pos + window_len]
        if print_debug > 0:
            print("Checking window[{:4}]: {} ".format(pos,
                                                      data_to_string(window)))
        found_pos = find_window(data[pos + 1:], window)
        # If the window is not matched in the data following the window
        # then the window list is unique.
        if found_pos == NOT_FOUND:
            return pos

        if print_debug > 0:
            # Note that the found position returned from find_window() was
            # with respect to pos + 1; the first parameter value passed in.
            # Add pos + 1 to get the file offset location for debug.
            found_pos += pos + 1
            match = data[found_pos:found_pos + window_len]
            print("Found match @   {:4} : {}".format(found_pos,
                                                     data_to_string(match)))
    return NOT_FOUND


def main():
    ''' Ye ole main() '''
    global print_debug

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Search a file for a repeating sequence')

    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',  type=str, default='test_data.txt', help="the file to read")
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--wlen',  type=int, default=20,              help="the window length")
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', type=int, default=0,               help="debugging print level")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    file_name = args.file
    window_len = args.wlen
    print_debug = args.debug
    print("file: '{}', window_len: {}, debug={}".format(file_name, window_len, print_debug))

    data = read_hex_file(file_name)
    if print_debug > 0:
        print("Read {} bytes from file '{}'".format(len(data), file_name))
    unique_pos = find_unique(data, window_len)

    if unique_pos == NOT_FOUND:
        print("No unique windows of length {} found".format(window_len))
    else:
        print("Unique window of length {} found at pos = {}".format(window_len,
                                                                    unique_pos))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How would I change the code to work if the hex values were not separated by whitespace? I'm interested in this as well, but my files are not separated, I read them in as r+b and use .hex(), and they're therefor not separated. Thank you natersoz & @OP.

Comment: Edited the code to do that. Are you people in the same class?

Comment: Yeah, I assume so, btw, you forgot to close the file in read_hex_file. And thank you once again.

Comment: Glad you caught that. It might count as points off!  :)

Answer (score 0):

If your datafile is not too big, this solution may work:

```
# Format data as hex bytes separated by space regardless of how the file looks:
data = '''F6 03 04 AA F3 03 03 AA F7 03 00 AA F4 02 40 F9 F3 03 03 AA F7 03 00 AA F4 02 40 F9
E8 51 00 F0 08 B1 2A 91 E0 03 14 AA E1 03 02 AA 08 B1 2A 91 E0 03 14 AA E1 03 02 AA
E2 03 08 AA 2F 01 00 94 F5 03 00 AA 75 01 00 B4 2F 01 00 94 F5 03 00 AA 75 01 00 B4
E0 03 17 AA E1 03 15 AA E2 03 16 AA 66 01 00 94 E1 03 15 AA E2 03 16 AA 66 01 00 94
F6 03 00 AA F6 00 00 34 E0 03 14 AA E1 03 15 AA F6 00 00 34 E0 03 14 AA E1 03 15 AA
F9 04 00 94 05 00 00 14 F6 03 1A 32 03 00 00 14 05 00 00 14 F6 03 1A 32 03 00 00 14
16 00 80 52 75 02 00 F9 E0 03 16 AA FD 7B 43 A9 75 02 00 F9 E0 03 16 AA FD 7B 43 A9
F4 4F 42 A9 F6 57 41 A9 F8 5F C4 A8 C0 03 5F D6 F6 57 41 A9 F8 5F C4 A8 C0 03 5F D6'''
data = data.replace('\n', ' ')  # Replacing newlines with <space>

unique_length = 2                   # Unique sequence length in no. of hex bytes:
data_length = (len(data)+1) // 3    # Data length in hex bytes
unique_list = []                    # List to contain unique sequences

# Loop through data and extract every possible unique string of unique_length hex bytes
for x in range(data_length-unique_length+1):
    test_string = data[3*x : 3*x+3*unique_length-1]
    if data.count(test_string) == 1:   # Is there just the one?
        unique_list.append(test_string)

print(unique_list)
```

Adjust the value of `unique_length` to your choice.